# ASP .NET Core 2 MVC error NU1202 creating project on VS 2017 and NET CLI

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have installed VS2017 15.3.0 and .NET Core 2.0 and have created a default Web MVC application on VS 2017 and I got the following errors:

> Error NU1202
>
> Package System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1 supports: netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>
> Error NU1202
>
> Package System.IO.Compression 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.IO.Compression 4.1.0
>
> supports:
>
> - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
> - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
> - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
> - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
> - netstandard1.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.1)
> - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
> - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
> - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
> - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
> - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
> - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
> - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
> - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)

The same errors occours using NET CLI with the command: dotnet new mvc

I've tried update nuget: Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine -Version 4.3.0

But it doesn´t works.

So I have dotnet core2 installed, with Visual Studio 2017 with update 15.3.0 and NuGet 4.3.0

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue, albeit with different assemblies, [and the suggestion from MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/132877/view.html) was to run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console):

```
PM> dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

Comment: This worked! Run this command in the Package Manager Console inside VS and let it complete until you see the `PM>` indicator again.