# How can I fix microsoft code analysis package compatibility issue?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm receiving these 4 distressing errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 supports: portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7) 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 supports: portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)             

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 supports: portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)             

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 supports: portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
```

It didn't show up back in the past but after a few repairs/modifications/reinstalls of Visual Studio it now shows up. I need to make an MVC in core 1.1 and I just want to get rid of these errors. Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Microsoft documentation for this error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings).

This error is commonly caused by a NuGet package not supporting the project's target framework. Check your referenced packages and make sure that they support your target framework, and try removing and re-adding them to find out which one(s) are causing the errors.

You can also try the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876615/8718143), where they recommend running the following command: 
`dotnet nuget locals all --clear`